# Spring Boot Selenium - Github Login cannot work org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplateHandler Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, github, junit

I tried to implement a selenium example to login github through Spring Boot.

When I ran the test method, I got this error shown below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@3d3c886f testClass = com.github.selenium.process.GithubProcess, locations = [], classes = [com.github.selenium.SeleniumApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4310d43, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@27f981c6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@771a660, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1ffaf86, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@169dd363], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplateHandler
```

How can I fix it?

Here is the code shown below.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class GithubProcess {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    String baseUrl = "https://github.com/login";

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        // github login through selenium with username and password
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        WebElement usernameOrEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("login_field"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']"));

        String usernameOrEmailField = "my-username-or-email";
        String passwordField = "my-password";

        usernameOrEmail.sendKeys(usernameOrEmailField);
        password.sendKeys(passwordField);
        signInButton.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }
}
```

Here are my dependency defined in pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <selenium.version>4.6.0</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.3.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Selenium-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Webdriver Manager-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit5-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After defining this **dependency** in the **pom.xml**, the issue disappeared.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```